# Как передавать аргументы из функции в функцию в Python

Tags: python

Задумался над тем, что я что-то делаю не так, передавая аргументы через функцию в другую функцию.

Пример:

```
def foo():
    name = 'Вася'
    bar(name)

def bar(name):
    ...
    log(name)

def log(name):
    ...
    print name
```

Подскажите, как правильно передать аргумент из foo() в log() через bar()?
Есть вариант через глобальные переменные, но насколько это правильно в данном варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Функция канонически *всегда* должна возвращать значение. Функция, не возвращающая значение - это исключение, а не правило.

```
def foo():
    name = 'Вася'
    return name

def bar(name=foo()):
    name += "!"
    return name

def log(name=bar()):
    name += "?"
    return name

print(log())
```

> ```
> Вася!?
> ```

Comment: Ну, в языках, в которых нет разницы между процедурами и функциями, функции никому ничего не обязаны )

Answer (score 1):

Можно инкапсулировать всё это хозяйство в один класс, например. Тогда снаружи класса не будет валяться лишних переменных. Но при этом функции внутри класса будут иметь непосредственный доступ к нужным им полям класса без необходимости прямо передавать параметры этим функциям:

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def bar(self):
        # ...
        self.log()

    def log(self):
        print(self.name)

vasya = Something('Вася')
vasya.bar()
```

Вывод:

```
Вася
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    name = 'Вася'
    bar(name)

def bar(name):
    log(name)

def log(name):
    print(name)
```

Именно так, foo создает локальную переменную с именем, которая просто переходит в локальную переменную других функций 2 раза

По сути создается 3 переменных, но все они указывают на одну и ту же строку 'Вася'